# Oracle SQL: How would I find out which column contains NULL values in a JOIN?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying get a query result of empty job positions within the company in a mock-up scheme. The syntax seems fine to me but it returns columns with empty rows and on top of that, these columns are all the columns combined together from 2 tables described below.
Here is my code:

```
SELECT * FROM HR.jobs
Left JOIN HR.employees ON HR.jobs.job_id = HR.employees.job_id
WHERE HR.employees.job_id = NULL;
```

There are these 2 tables called HR.employees with your regular column names, primary key being employee_id and a foreign key job_id. The other one is HR.jobs and contains primary key job_id and other generic columns like job_title, min/max_salary etc.

I can't tell whether it's the JOIN that is wrong or WHERE clause. I checked out w3schools on where clauses and joins and [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join) too and it would seem that I need (A∪B) - B but it just produces different result, than expected.

Comment: SELECT * FROM HR.jobs as a, HR.employees as b where a.job_id = b.job_id and b.job_id is NULL;

Comment: Try with this , if I understand your question.

Comment: `IS NULL`, not `= NULL`.

Comment: @ShadabSiddiqui it produced the same result as mine. I need only the columns of HR.jobs returned and instead got from both tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff tried that but it produced the same result. Logic of the code is faulty, I just fail to see where and how.

Comment: WHERE HR.jobs.job_id IS NULL;. Try this with your query

Comment: @ShadabSiddiqui same output again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `is null`
2. Use aliases
3. Specify which columns do you want to output

```sql
SELECT j.* -- only columns from hr.jobs
FROM HR.jobs j
Left JOIN HR.employees e 
  ON j.job_id = e.job_id
WHERE e.job_id is NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it did output only the HR.jobs columns. Wasn't sure whether their entries were empty but this code seems foolproof. I will try to get used to aliases, haven't really used them much.